# Check if user can comment in a post if he has that post registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I validate if an user belongs to the post he's watching? if not don't allow to comment on the post, i tried with an if and I'm using a has_many model-relationship
like `User(devise)` `UserPost(model)` `Post` and `comments(belongs_to post)`

I tried doing `<%Membership.where(user_id: self.id, group_id: group.id).any?%>`
but i get an error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column courses.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."user_id" = ...
                                              ^
: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."user_id" = $1 AND "courses"."course_id" = $2 LIMIT $3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

playing with the code I tried this and it worked:

```
  <%if current_user.courses.exists?(@course.id)%>
    do ....
  <%end%>
```